# What is the sum of half of the choices (weighted)?

Tags: combinatorics

I'd like to get the exact value of the following sum:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil \frac{k}{2} \rceil}{({k \choose i}\cdot i)}$

I'd also like to know the asymptotic limits of the function.

Comment: What is k choose i if k is not integral? Otherwise, why the ceiling function? EDIT -- looks like it's fixed.

Comment: *Very* related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7757

Comment: @gatoatigrado: Sorry, I'm not the best LaTeXter yet.  @J.M.: I'm hoping that the asymptotics are different.  It would mean that I have a noteworthy algorithm for a multiplication problem.

Comment: I found this question:   http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Comment: You can factor out the $i$ like this:  $i\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil \frac{k}{2} \rceil}{{k \choose i}}$

Comment: @muntoo: No you cannot. Definitely not.

Comment: I believe I've found a way to construct the generating function for this. I'm hoping I can get the information from this... It will take some time to make sure it is correct. I use three generating functions to exchange information to get the factorial term. Two contain all terms (on one side) except for possibly the middle. The third is Pascal's triangle; I subtract both sides to see if there is a middle term to add. I then use the terms on one side to construct functions that successively add terms closer to the middle. Summing this should give the correct GF for the original problem.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, woops! You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\binom{k}{i} i = k \binom{k-1}{i-1}$ to get

$\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil k/2 \rceil} \binom{k}{i} = k\sum_{j=0}^{\lceil k/2 \rceil - 1} \binom{k-1}{j}$

If $k = 2m$ is even then

$k\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m-1}{j} = k 2^{2m-2} = k2^{k-2}$

If $k = 2m+1$ is odd then

$k\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{2m}{j} = k \left(2^{2m-1} +\frac{1}{2} \binom{2m}{m}\right) = k\left(2^{k-2} + \frac{1}{2} \binom{k-1}{(k-1)/2}\right)$

For the asymptotics, $\frac{k}{2} \binom{k-1}{(k-1)/2} \approx 2^{k-1} \sqrt{\frac{k}{2\pi}}$.

Comment: Very simple!  Excellent!