# Simplifying $\sum_{i=1}^n {1\over i(i+1)}$ to ${n\over n+1}$

Tags: summation

I need to get from this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {1\over i(i+1)}$$
to:
$${n\over n+1}$$
or:
$${1 - {1\over n+1}}$$
I have tried looking for sums identities with fractions, using WolframAlpha.com (that's how I got the results above) and reading my textbook, but I don't get how to manipulate this. Thank you.

***edit*: What I did:**

Based on Idris' answer, I took the sum to be:
$${1\over1}-{1\over 1+1}+{1\over 2}-{1\over2+1}+{1\over 3}-{1\over3+1}+...+{1\over n}-{1\over n+1}$$
With that, the groups like $-{1\over 1+1}+{1\over 2}$ cancel each other out (telescoping?) and in the end what's left is:
$$1-{1\over n+1}$$ the result that I was looking for! Thank you again, Idris!

Comment: See also: [What is the formula for $1/(1\cdot 2)+1/(2\cdot 3)+1/(3\cdot 4)+\ldots +1/(n(n+1))$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/286024) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/286024).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HInt: Write $1/i(i+1)=1/i-1/(i+1)$ then the sum telescopes.

UPDATE1: Telescopes, each two neighboring terms cancel, like this
$$SUM= [1/1\color{red}{-1/(1+1)}]+[\color{red}{1/2}-1/(2+1)]+....$$
UPDATE 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Hmm. "telescopes" is a method I don't know, but thanks, I'll read into that.

Comment: Telescopes means that terms cancel. Using the partial fraction decomposition the sum is equal to 

$$1 - 1/2 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/3 - 1/4 + \cdots$$

Comment: @sempiedram. You are welcome. You can improve the presentation: instead of one line use two columns (the left one contains the $1/i$ values and the right one contains the $-1/(i+1)$ values, and the cancellation would be in diagonals, its beautiful !

Comment: Yes, quite interesting how it works.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Telescoping sum]
Here is a picture showing the two columns and the cancellations in diagonals

Comment: Cool, I was thinking about simply using parenthesis to group them, but that's also a possibility I guess

Answer (score 0):

Another telescope:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac 1{i(i+1)}&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac i{i+1}-\frac{i-1}i\right)\\
&=\frac n{n+1}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$