# Summation of ${\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}}$ using equations

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, combinations, geometric-series

I was trying to solve the summation:

> $${\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}}$$

I started something like:

$${\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n}$$
$${\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 2^0 \qquad(1)}$$
Similarly,
$${\Rightarrow \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 2^1 \qquad(2)}$$
$${\vdots}$$
$${\Rightarrow \sum_{k=n}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 2^{n-1} \qquad(n)}$$

---

On adding the above n equations, we get,
$${\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} = n2^n - (2^0 + 2^1 + \cdots + 2^{n-1})}$$
As the expression inside brackets on RHS is a GP, the sum comes up as,
$${S_n = 2^0\left(\frac{2^n - 1}{2-1}\right) = 2^n - 1}$$
$${\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} = n2^n - 2^n + 1 \neq n2^{n-1}}$$

I've checked my solution many times and have searched for similar solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123655/evaluate-and-prove-by-induction-sum-kn-choose-k-sum-frac1kk1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/how-to-prove-this-binomial-identity-sum-r-0n-r-n-choose-r-n2n-1), but there was no answer using this method. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're missing terms. I think you should have $2^n - 2^1 - 2^0$, for instance in equation 2.

Comment: Eastablish & use $k\binom nk =n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Comment: It would not occur to me not to use the differentiation trick in a highly voted answer to the linked question. Anyway, something's wrong in your equations $(2)$ thru $(n)$. Surely $$\sum_{k=2}^n\binom n k=2^n-\binom n 0-\binom n1=2^n-1-n$$ and
$$\sum_{k=n}^n\binom nk=1.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each step you are saying that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}{n\choose k}=2^m$ which is not true!  What is true is that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}{m\choose k}=2^m$. Be careful, note the difference.

The way to do it is using $k{n\choose k}=n{n-1\choose k-1}$.
So at the end your sum is equal to 
$$\sum_{k=1}^nn{n-1\choose k-1}=n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose j}=n2^{n-1}$$

Comment: The asker already checked out two threads. Your answer is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7761/11619), I think.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k{n \choose k}} =
\bbox[10px,#fee]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k{n \choose k}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left(n - k\right){n \choose n - k}
\\[5mm] = &\
n\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k} -
\bbox[10px,#fee]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k{n \choose k}}
\\[5mm] &\
\implies
\bbox[10px,#fee]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k{n \choose k}} =
{1 \over 2}\,n\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\color{red}{1}^{k} =
{1 \over 2}\,n\left(1 + \color{red}{1}\right)^{n}
\\[5mm] &\ \implies
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k{n \choose k}} = n\,2^{n - 1}}
\end{align}