# Combinatorial proofs - how?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I'm suppose to proof the following with combinatorial proofs.

1)$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {a+i \choose i} = {a+n+1 \choose n}$$

2)$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} i{n \choose i} = n2^{n-1}$$

3)$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}^2 = {2n \choose n}$$

Any ideas how this is done ?

Comment: Do you know the "counting in two ways" method?

Comment: Yes, but I have a hard time using it.

Comment: For the first do an induction on n Note that
$\binom{a+n+1}{n}+\binom{a+n+1}{n+1}=\binom{a+n+2}{n+1}$ by Pascal's recurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:
[image]

For the second one check out this other post: [Combinatorial proof of $\sum^{n}_{i=1}\binom{n}{i}i=n2^{n-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388587/combinatorial-proof-of-sumn-i-1-binomnii-n2n-1)

For the third just write the summand as $\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}$. Imagine you have $2n$ students and you split the class into two chunks of $n$. You want to pick $n$ to go on a trip. You can choose first $0$ from one half, and the take other half, or one from one half and $n-1$ from the other half and so on. Or you could just straight up pick them without the partition in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways.

Comment: Thanks, number 2 and 3 are useful. But I don't see any proof for the first one.

Comment: @Franklin check this site. Q5 can prove your number 1.
http://abc7434221math.blogspot.tw/2015/04/my-discrete-mathematics-midterm-exam.html#more