# Choosing a $k$ person committee with chairperson from a group of $n$ people confusion

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics, combinations

The following is from: http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~bremer/Teaching/Math163/Homework/HomeworkFiles/Solution03.pdf

[image]

I am having trouble understanding these identities and the solutions. I am confused as to the LHS because I thought the number of ways to choose a $k$ person committee with a chairperson from a group of $n$ people is $k \cdot \binom{n}{k}$.

This solution seems likes its counting the same thing but giving another answer. Why the summation?

Comment: The summation is because the committee can consist of $1,2,\dots,n$ people.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/388596/86425

Answer (score 3):

Both sides count committees of all sizes. On the right-hand side, the arbitrary size arises because $2^{n-1}$ allows every non-chairperson to be in the committee or not independently. On the left-hand side, we form chaired committees of $k$ people, so we have to sum over $k$ to count all committees of all sizes. You're right in thinking that $k\binom nk$ counts the number of ways to choose a $k$-person committee with a chairperson from a group of $n$ people.