# Double counting $n2^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove by double-counting that

$$k2^{k-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} i\binom{k}{i}$$

where $n$ is a positive integer.

I did it algebraically. However, the professor told me that I have to do this also by double-counting but I am not sure how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove this binomial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n {r {n \choose r}} = n2^{n-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/how-to-prove-this-binomial-identity-sum-r-0n-r-n-choose-r-n2n-1) You can see many answers here, including by expansions, by double-counting elements of a set, by algebraic manipulation, and the entire lot.

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7767/362866) answer of the cited question is what OP is after.

Comment: See also: [Combinatorial proof of $\sum^{n}_{i=1}\binom{n}{i}i=n2^{n-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388587)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the problem of forming a committee with a president from a group of $n$ people.

On one hand, you can first fix a president ($n$ choices) and then choose a subset of the remaining people to form the committee ($2^{n-1}$ choices). This gives you LHS.

On the other, you can fix a size $k$ (between $1$ and $n$) first and then pick a committee with $k$ people ($\binom{n}{k}$ many choices) and then pick a president from that ($k$ choices). Sum over all possible $k$ to get the RHS.