# Proof by induction $\sum_{k=1}^{n}$ $k \binom{n}{k}$ $= n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ for each natural number $n$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, binomial-coefficients

Prove by induction that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}$ $k \binom{n}{k}$ $= n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ for each natural number $n$.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683733/sum-of-k-n-choose-k-is-n2n-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that: $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1}$. Thus: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k\binom{n+1}{k} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k\binom{n}{k} + \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k\binom{n}{k-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} + \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)\binom{n}{k} = 2\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k} + \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2\cdot n2^{n-1} + 2^n = (n+1)2^n$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to derive this result. By the binomial theorem,
$$(1+x)^n =\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$
Differentiate both sides. 
$$n(1+x)^{n-1} =\sum^{n}_{k=0} k\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}$$
Substitute $x=1$
$$n2^{n-1} =\sum^{n}_{k=0} k\binom{n}{k} =\sum^{n}_{k=1} k\binom{n}{k} $$