# Proof Verification for $n2^{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

$(1+x)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$ by binomial theorem

$\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n =\frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$

$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}$

Plug in $x=1$

$n(2)^{n-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}$

$Q.E.D.$

I've been told my derivative of the $RHS$ is incorrect, I disagree. What do you guys think? Is this proof trash or valid?

Comment: I think you should write the indices of the sums on the RHS, then you can maybe see if the derivative is correct or wrong. However the proof is *probably* correct. :)

Comment: @Ale I've edited my answer. I took the derivative term by term and it seems to be correct. My professor said I was wrong, and I would love to prove her incorrect.

Comment: I think you should also edit the title, but the proof looks correct to me.

Comment: Note the sum in the title and the sum in the proof are not the same.

Comment: @DavidH what do you mean? We start with the binomial expansion than work our way to the sum in title. We reindex because the first term becomes $0$ when we take the derivative.

Comment: The special case $n=2$ provides an easy counterexample. The value of the sum in the title is $\sum_{k=1}^{2}2\binom{2}{k}=2\binom{2}{1}+2\binom{2}{2}=6$. But $n2^{n-1}$ evaluates to $2\cdot 2^{1}=4$.

Comment: Typo, my bad. I've fixed it in the title I think.