# I have a algorithm and from the post its time complexity is: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom nk= n 2^{n-1}$

Tags: summation, algorithms, binomial-coefficients

I have a algorithm and from the post its time complexity is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom nk= n  2^{n-1}$$

My question is, how to get the result $n2^{n-1}$ need some help . thanks

Comment: Duplicate I guess: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7757/321264.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of the binomial coefficients,
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k $$
Taking the derivative of both sides, we obtain
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}kx^k $$
Now let $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom nk=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom {n-1}{k-1}=n2^{n-1} $$

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the "absorption identity"

$$ k \binom n k = n \binom {n-1} {k-1},$$

which is valid for all integer $k$. This gives

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom n k &= n\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
&= n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {n-1} k \\
&= n2^{n-1}.
\end{aligned}$$