# Prove Prove $n2^{n - 1}$ = $\sum_{i\geq 0}^{} {n \choose i}i$ algebraically and using induction.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

Suppose $n \in$ natural numbers.

Prove $n2^{n - 1}$ =  $\sum_{i\geq 0}^{} {n \choose i}i$

I have proven it combinatorially. Just having troubles algebraically and using induction.

Comment: @GAVD $\binom{n}{i} = 0$ for $i>n$, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: See also [How to prove this binomial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n {r {n \choose r}} = n2^{n-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7757) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7757).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $\binom{n+1}{i+1}(i+1)=\binom{n}{i}(n+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 0$, both sides are $0$; assume the result holds for some $n$.  Then we have \begin{align*}
\sum_{i \geq 0 } \binom{n+1}{i}i &= \sum_{i\geq 0} \binom{n}{i}i + \sum_{i \geq 0} \binom{n}{i-1}i \\
&= n 2^{n-1} + 2^n + \sum_{i \geq 0} \binom{n}{i-1}(i-1) \\
&= n 2^{n-1} + 2^n + n 2^{n-1} \\
&= (n+1)2^n.
\end{align*}