# Show ($n+1$)$2^n$ = $\sum_{i\geq 0}^{} {n + 1\choose i}i$ algebraically.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

Show ($n+1$)$2^n$ =  $\sum_{i\geq 0}^{} {n + 1\choose i}i$  algebraically.

I know $2^n$ = $\sum_{i\geq 0}^{} {n\choose i}$. But how do I manipulate the $(n+1)$ to make it look like the right side?

Comment: Formal derivatives in the formal power series should still be counted as algebraic, I think.

Comment: See also [How to prove this binomial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n {r {n \choose r}} = n2^{n-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7757) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7757).

Answer (score 2):

Using the binomial theorem, we have

$$(1+x)^{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose i}x^i.$$

Taking polynomial derivative with respect to $x$, we have

$$(n+1)(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose i}\,i\,x^{i-1}.$$

Setting $x=1$, we obtain

$$(n+1)2^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose i}\,i.$$

Only using derivatives of polynomials. Still algebraic?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{n+1}{k}\cdot k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}(n+1)\\[6pt]
&=(n+1)\,2^n
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n+1}{i} x^i
\end{align}
with respect to $x$ and then plug in $x=1$.