# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l} l\right)=n \times 3^{n-1}$ with a combinatoric argument

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> I want to prove
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l} l\right)=n \times 3^{n-1}$$
> with combinatoric argumentation.

I have tried to understand it by comparing it with similiar problems. One such problem would be to prove the following equation with combinatoric argumentation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {{n}\choose{k}}*k = n* 2^{n-1}$$  The proof would be

> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7767/788271

How can i apply that solution to the given problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing algebraically.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l} l\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\dfrac{n!k!}{k!(n-k)!l!(k-l)!}l\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\dfrac{n!l}{(n-k)!l!(k-l)!}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\dfrac{n!l}{(n-k)!l!(k-l)!}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\sum_{k=l}^{n}\dfrac{n!l}{(n-k)!l!(k-l)!}
\quad\text{(when in doubt, reverse the order of summation)}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!l}{l!}\sum_{k=l}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(n-k)!(k-l)!}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!l}{l!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}\dfrac{1}{(n-(k+l))!(k+l-l)!}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!l}{l!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}\dfrac{1}{(n-k-l)!k!}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!l}{l!(n-l)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}\dfrac{(n-l)!}{(n-k-l)!k!}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}l\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}\binom{n-l}{k}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}l\binom{n}{l}2^{n-l}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}(n-l)\binom{n}{n-l}2^{l}\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{n}n\binom{n}{n-l}2^{l}-\sum_{l=0}^{n}l\binom{n}{l}2^{l}\\
&=n3^n-\sum_{l=0}^{n}l\binom{n}{l}2^{l}\\
&=n3^n-2n3^{n-1}
\qquad (*)\\
&=n \times 3^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

(*)
$(1+x)^n
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k
$
so
$n(1+x)^{n-1}
=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}
$
so,
with $x = 2$,
$n3^{n-1}
=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k2^{k-1}
$
or
$2n3^{n-1}
=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k2^{k}
$

Answer (score 3):

We have $n$ people, One of them will be the Captain & all the others will be one of $3$ types (A,B or C).

Choose $n-k$ to be of type $A$, now choose $k-l$ out of the remaining $k$ to be of type $B$, now choose one of the remainig $l$ to be the captain and let the final $l-1$ be of type $C$.

Comment: Nice simplification of the sum. Still, I would not see how this expresses the given sum above, or how to actually calculate all the possibilities (without knowing the solution). Does this 'method' of counting has a name?

Comment: @Cornman Click on tags ... & choose "combinatorial proofs" ... this is a standard technique to count the same thing in two ways. In this example the first paragraph is clearly $n3^{n-1}$ and the second paragraph is ... \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{l=0}^{k} \binom{k}{l} l.
\end{eqnarray*}